# Sql query looping over multiple dynamic schemas en combing results in an union

Tags: sql, postgresql, for-loop, dynamic

So I have the problem that the PostgreSql database I am using has multiple retailers each as a schema. These retailers are defined in a table in the public schema. So I need a sql script dat can first retrieve all these retailers from the public.tenants table and loop through them to Select the retailer schema with the .programs table:

```
SELECT * FROM a.programs;
SELECT * FROM b.programs;
```

I have tried some variations, but cannot find a way to figure this one out.

The SQL script I have tried:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
    tables CURSOR FOR
        SELECT tenantid
        FROM public.tenants;
BEGIN 
FOR scheme_name IN tables LOOP
    EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %s.%s',scheme_name, 'programs');
END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

This gave the following output:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM (a).programs
                          ^
QUERY:  SELECT * FROM (a).programs
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 8 at EXECUTE
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
SQL state: 42601
Context: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 8 at EXECUTE
```

How do I make the `EXECUTE` not take `in ()` around the dynamic schema name? Or is this application not possible at all?

Please help me out with this one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple errors. 
The immediate error is that you are referencing the *record* from the loop, not the single field of that record and the parentheses are part of the default string display of a record.

You also should be using `%I` for placeholder intended for identifiers to properly deal with quoting.

So the immediate error is fixed using this:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
    tables CURSOR FOR
        SELECT tenantid
        FROM public.tenants;
BEGIN 
FOR rec IN tables LOOP
    EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %I.%I', rec.tenantid, 'programs');
END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

But this is still not going to work because you can't return a result like that from an anonymous PL/PgSQL block. You need to put that into a function:

```
create or replace function all_programs()
  returns setof a.programs -- or returns table (...)
as
$$
declare
    tables CURSOR FOR
        SELECT tenantid
        FROM public.tenants;
BEGIN 
  FOR rec IN tables LOOP
    return query EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %I.%I', rec.tenantid, 'programs');
  END LOOP;
END
```

$$
   language plgpgsql;

Then use:

```
select *
from all_programs();
```

Comment: Thank you! I have to do a few things before it will work how I want it too, but can now proceed :)